# Object ownership in C++ (MVC pattern)

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, ownership

I understand MVC pattern well enough, but there is surprisingly low amount of information for practical implementation in C++. For this application, I'm using `wxWidgets` and `boost::depedency_injection`, but the situation should be generic.

In C++ 11/14 we have strict rules for object ownership: object is either shared across owners, or unique to one owner. We have also old-style pointers for object non-owned by callee.

So, the question is: who owns which object (model/view/controller) in MVC in C++?

My guess for now:

`Views` owns `controllers` which are injected by `boost:di` as `unqiue_ptr`. `Controllers` are owned by `views` and do *not* store state in any forms (only procedures that executes on `models` catalog). `Models` themselves are shared between all `controllers` via injecting them as `shared_ptr` and are used to store result and provide data for `controllers` operations

Is it right for MVC?

Comment: Why voting down to close?

Comment: Well there exist so many MVC variants that it is difficult to answer. But no, controllers are not owned by views, it should be the contrary, because controller is the functional bridge between both view and model. Model is attached to views, thus views can owns model. This may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929957/mvc-approach-with-c.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I've read that question and answer already, but it is just a theory of MVC. And I'm asking about implementation specific problem

Comment: Then you should have understood that usually controllers are not injected to views... Views and models are injected into controllers and models are injected into views. Injection can be dynamic or static, in which cases the nature of ownership may vary... Give us what you tried to do, and we may answer more accurately. More generally I doubt view/controller ownership should be limited to restrictive ownership as a view may be controlled by several controllers.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès So, if I need to open new view is it controller which is doing that? How the startup of application should work - should I have `startup controller` which opens a default view? What about MDI view -> should I treat them as single view, or should they be MDI child based? Can you write your comments as answer?

Comment: See examples in the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there exist so many MVC variants that it is difficult to answer. But no, controllers are not owned by views, it should be the contrary, because controller is the functional bridge between both view and model. Model is attached to views, thus views can owns model.

Examine that [first C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984296/model-view-controller-design-pattern-code-example) or that [second C++ example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/169892/). In the first there is "static" ownerships while in the second ownerships are much more volatiles.

Comment: What is the correct way to dynamically create controllers in such approach?